# Swift: Charts Filled Line & more

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts, line

I've come up this library on swift called: Charts
https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

I did my best to add some functionalities but for some other(listed under) I couldn't figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

**What i'm trying to do:**
- A filled Line chart (done)
- Remove Circle at coordinates. (done)
- remove all axis bars (Y+X) (todo)
- remove yAxis legend (todo)
- on the line, display value every x times (todo)

**What i've done:**

[image: Chart Graph]

**Extra**
- on touch display yValue above the touch
- gradient fill based on yValue
- Animate (done)

Here is my actual code:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    //print(dataPoints)
    //print(values)
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    //Coloring
    let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)


    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Temperatures")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    //draw as line
    lineChartDataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
    //fill graph
    lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
    //color graph
    lineChartDataSet.colors = [color]

    lineChartView.data = lineChartData
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
    lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .EaseInCubic)
    //remove coordinate circles
    lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    //remove xAxis line
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

    //remove description
    lineChartView.descriptionText = ""


}
```

I'm looking to:
remove all axis bars (Y+X)
remove yAxis legend
on the line, display value every x times
And to display the value when graph touched.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Comment: Trying to add the functionality i listed at the top of the post. I repeated them at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove all axis bars and legends you could do this:

This is a snippet from my code:

```
popularityChartView.descriptionText = ""
    popularityChartView.noDataText = Constants.messages.NO_POPULARITY_CHART_DATA
    popularityChartView.noDataTextDescription = ""
    popularityChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:236/255, green:236/255,blue:236/255,alpha:1)

    popularityChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.xAxis.gridColor = UIColor(red:220/255, green:220/255,blue:220/255,alpha:1)
    popularityChartView.xAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.5
    popularityChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    popularityChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

    popularityChartView.leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines()
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.zeroLineWidth = 0
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false

    popularityChartView.rightAxis.removeAllLimitLines()
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.leftAxis.zeroLineWidth = 0
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
```

[My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuyMI.png)

Hope it helps.